# Thread Local only initializing to Zero

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, thread-local

I was implementing a Thread Local example using following code, I thought I'd be getting random numbers in the output but when the `threadLocal.get()` method is called I get a zero for all threads n output, am I missing something here. Here is my code and the output, will deeply appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

```
package concurrency;

public class ThreadLocalExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SubLocalClass subLocalClass = new SubLocalClass();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
             Thread thread = new Thread(subLocalClass);
             thread.start();
             thread.join();

        }
    }

}

class SubLocalClass implements Runnable{
    private ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocal =  new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
        protected Integer initialValue() {
            return 1000;

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void run() {
        threadLocal.set((int) Math.random());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+" "+
        Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+threadLocal.get());
    }

}
```

And the output that I am getting is this

```
12 Thread-0 0
13 Thread-1 0
14 Thread-2 0
15 Thread-3 0
16 Thread-4 0
17 Thread-5 0
18 Thread-6 0
19 Thread-7 0
20 Thread-8 0
21 Thread-9 0
```

why `0` for `threadLocal.get()` for all the threads, shouldn't it be publishing random numbers?

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. `(int) Math.random()` is `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the thread local to zero:

```
threadLocal.set((int) Math.random());
```

Because `Math.random()` returns a double between `0` and `1`, when you cast it to an int it will yield `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `Math.random()` function returns pseudorandom `double` greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. When you cast this number to `int` value, it cuts off the fractional part. As result, in most cases you will receive 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

If you like a random number between 0 and 1000, you could use it like

```
threadlocal.set((int)(Math.random() * 1000));
```